# Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.DynamicThread cannot be cast to org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I am currently using Blazemeter to run load (performance) tests for a Java application, but I am getting this error. When I run it locally on my machine, this error does not occur.

Under 'scenario definition' my test starts off with a standard jmeter thread group. I did a bit of searching and realised that com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.DynamicThread comes from the CustomThreadGroups plugin, so I have also uploaded the appropriate jar file plugin jmeter-plugins-casutg-2.9.jar file.

[Screenshot of scenario definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyNdB.png)

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5t2b.png)

Would just like to check if there is some other jar file that I need to upload to solve this error, or if there is another method to solve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should raise this form of questions to [BlazeMeter Support](https://www.blazemeter.com/support/) as they should have better understanding of their infrastructure.

With regards to your question itself, most probably you're suffering from a form of a [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell) as:

- BlazeMeter uses [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) under the hood for kicking off JMeter tests which automatically downloads [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) so it might be the case your plugins versions clash with the plugins at their end
- You need to remove one of [joda-time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) libraries as you cannot tell for sure which one will be loaded into [classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) and in case of API inconsistency you can get unpredictable errors.